# Checkbox field in symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

Good morning everyone! Is a form of.

Class ReleasesType:

```
$builder
    ->add('doid', 'text')
    ->add('dourl', 'text')
     ->add('artists', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'MReleaseCoreBundle:Artists',
        'property' => 'name',
        'expanded' => true ,
        'multiple' => true                
    ));
```

Сonnection with them one-to-many:

Class 'Artists':

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ReleasesArtists" , mappedBy="artists" , cascade={"all"})
 * */
private $da;

public function __construct() {
    $this->da = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

Class 'ReleasesArtists':

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Releases", inversedBy="da")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="releases_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * */ 
private $releases;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Artists", inversedBy="da")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="artists_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * */
private $artists;
```

And of course the entity 'Releases':

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ReleasesArtists" , mappedBy="releases", cascade={"all"} , orphanRemoval=true)
 */
private $da;

public function getArtists() {

    $artists = new ArrayCollection();

    foreach($this->da as $p) {
        $artists[] = $p->getArtists()->getName();
    }

    return $artists;

}    

public function addDa($da) {
    $this->da[] = $da;
}

public function setArtists($artists) {

    foreach($artists as $p) {
        $po = new \MRelease\CoreBundle\Entity\ReleasesArtists();

        $po->setReleases($this);
        $po->setArtists($p);

        $this->addDa($po);
    }

}
```

Connection is working correctly, all outputs. But does not "checked". In what may be the problem? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Into your controller, where you build and output your form, you have to do something like this

```
public function myFooAction(Request $request, $releasesId)
{
  $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('YourBundleName:Releases');
  $releasesObject = $repo->findOneById($releasesId);
  $form = $this->createForm(new ReleasesType(), $releasesObject);
  return $this->render('YourBundle::TemplateToRender, array('form'=>$form);
}
```

---

**What happen here, and why is working?**

I've made some assumptions as you don't provide any controller code. First of all, I assume that you have an action like `myFooAction()` where you do form operation and I suppose, also, that you pass to this action an `id` for load object from DB and tie it to your form - if I understood correctly your question.
So, first line of action is for retrieve repository for this object. Once you've got repo, you can fetch your object (second line). On third line I use Symfony2 form's facility and "connect" object to his form type: with this, all values contained into this object will be reported into your form (so checkboxes will have correct value). Last line is for render form.

Obviously, your action logic could be different but concept expressed here could be replicated with "different" implementation everywhere.

Comment: My method:

<pre>
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('MReleaseCoreBundle:Releases')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Releases entity.');
        }
        
        $editForm = $this->createForm(new ReleasesType(), $entity);


        return $this->render('MReleaseCoreBundle:Releases:edit.html.twig', array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView()
        ));
</pre>

Comment: @Konstantin: and so? I can't understand what you're saying here. Is working? Not working? What's the issue? Please, help me understand :P

Comment: Bad with the English :)

Figured out what the problem is. The Getter do not need to display the title was:

$artists[] = $p->getArtists()->getName(); 
replace on 
$artists[] = $p->getArtists();